# fit image in the button on kivy

Tags: python, image, button, kivy, scale

I have a question, I'm making a small application interface with kivy. When making a button using an image, the image part does not scale according to the button, but when resizing according to the button, the image is skewed, but only needs to be affected on the application's screen (zoom in and out of the screen), the image will change. runs to the correct position and scales to the size of the button. Is there anyone who can help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNKak.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoT9Z.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpydb.png)

Comment: Please add Code to the question not as screenshot but as pasted text in `code` tags.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Button:
    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
    pos_hint: {'x': .39, 'y': .1}
    size_hint: .28, .15

    Image:
        id: my_image
        source: "name of the image"
        size: 350, 350
        allow_stretch: True
        allow_ratio: True
        keep_ratio: True
        center_x: self.parent.center_x
        center_y: self.parent.center_y
```